# is there any difference between assigning value to the variable inside of initState or not in Flutter StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I saw two ways to declare variables with StatefulWidget in many sample codes.

1. initialize variable with value (**firstCase**)
2. initialize variable without value and assign to value inside of initState (**secondCase**)

Is there any difference between these?
Or which one would be better code in practice?

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  Sample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  bool firstCase = false;
  bool secondCase;

  @override
  void initState() {
    secondCase = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In general you want to use initState. The main difference is that if you do NOT use initState you have no hot reload

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know hot reload thing.

Comment: InitState or not has no impact on hot reload.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you can create initialise your variable directly in the property, do so. It's better for readability (a single place to look for).

The only reason you'll want to use `initState` is for when you *cannot* initialise the variable directly from its declaration.

These situations are for the most part:

- your variable depends on `widget` or `context`
- it depends on `this`

For example, if you want to create an `AnimationController` you'll need to pass it `vsync: this`. But the following won't compile:

```dart
class MyState extends State with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final myController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this, // compile error, cannot use `this` on initialisers
  );
}
```

And you'd have to instead write:

```dart
class MyState extends State with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController myController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this, // OK
    );
  }
}
```

Although note that this specific example will soon change as a future version of Dart will introduce the `late` keyword, which then allows:

```dart
class MyState extends State with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final myController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this, // OK, not a compile error this time
  );
}
```

You may still need `initState` for variables that depends on `widget`/`context` though.