# why use initState() in flutter, when we can just initailize a variable in the very first line of code

Tags: flutter, dart, stateful, statefulwidget

is there a difference in these 3 codes:

First: when i call my function inside onInit().

```
@override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    fetchProductsFromAPI();
  }
```

Second: when i call my function inside of build method, in stateless widget.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    fetchProductsFromAPI();

    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: ShoppingPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Third: when i call my function outside of build method, in stateless widget.

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  fetchProductsFromAPI();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: ShoppingPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. You can read about flutter widget life cycle to have more details:

- [Life cycle in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479255/life-cycle-in-flutter)
- https://medium.flutterdevs.com/app-lifecycle-in-flutter-c248d894b830

In summary

### When you call your method outside of build method (your 3rd example).

This is what is usually recommended when you can do it.

See [is there any difference between assigning value to the variable inside of initState or not in Flutter StatefulWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59611811/is-there-any-difference-between-assigning-value-to-the-variable-inside-of-initst)

This will be run only once, when the class is created.

### Inside the `initState` (your 1st example)

At this moment, your widget is being created. Some getters are already available, like the `context`. This method is called only once.

### Inside the `build` method (your 2nd example)

This is usually the worst approach. Your method will be called for **each and every** build (you can consider 1 build = 1 frame) which can lead to poor performances. It is recommended to move those calls out of the `build` method when possible (and if it makes sense)

See [How to deal with unwanted widget build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build/52249579#52249579)

Answer (score 0):

First:
Put it on initState then the function `fetchProductsFromAPI` will only call first time your widget create

Second:
I highly recommend you do not use this approach, because build method will be trigger many time when widget need to rebuild, if you put it there, your app will be `fetchProductsFromAPI` at a lot of unexpected times.
Example when you need to call `setState()` for some changes, you don't want to call fetch API

Third:
This way will cause compile error, I don't think you can put it there like your code above